# Applescript, text entered with keystroke gets unformatted

Tags: text, applescript

Hi I'm using Applescript to enter text on a Safari Webpage.

One of the fields is a phone number that gets formatted with parenthesis as the user (human being) enters the numbers.

For instance if the user enters

> 123456789

the field ends up looking like this

> (12)3456789

For some reason when the same numbers are "entered" by my script they do not get formatted, even though they are exactly the same.

The script is quite simple

```
if Celular is not "" then
    keystroke Celular
    delay tiempo
end if
```

Any hint of what can I be doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Two options to try, are first, tab out of the field using a key code.

```
tell application "System Events" 
if Celular is not "" then
    keystroke Celular
    delay tiempo
    key code 48 -- a tab
end if
end
```

Alternately, you might try formatting the number yourself first:

```
set Celular to "5558675309"
set Celular to "(" & (text 1 thru 3 of Celular) & ") " & (text 4 thru 6 of Celular) & "-" & (text 7 thru 10 of Celular)
```

Comment: jweaks many thanks for  your answer. Option 1 didn't work. Option 2 worked but not completely. Let me explain it better. The field I'm working on is a postal code (not a celular even though I say so in my original post to simplify the explanation) and after using your suggestion the field is OK (i.e 12345-6778) but then the site is expected to retrieve the address out of the postal code and it doesn't happen. If I manually key in the same number then everything works like  a charm...

Comment: Try a 'return' key code 36 or 76 as well. You might need to do this with javascript, assuming it's a javascript box.